# webcontext on Artifactory 7.x

Tags: tomcat, artifactory, catalina, webcontext

I am struggling to set the webcontext on artifactory 7.x, but I cannot make it work no matter what I try. I know that on artifactory 5.x and 6.x there is an option in the menu for that, but in 7.x it's different.

Why I try :8082/ it's working, but I want to make it work under :8082/webcontext

Did anyone did this on Artifactory 7.x?

Answer (score 0):

Meantime, I have been able to get in touch with the jFrog Support, and they confirmed me that starting with version 7.0 and newer, Artifactory does not support `/webcontext` feature anymore, and they don't plan to support it.

Therefore `mydomain.com/artifactory-one` and `mydomain.com/artifactory-two` is not anymore possible, you have to do it using subdomains.

```
mydomain.com/artifactory-one -> artifactory-one.mydomain.com
mydomain.com/artifactory-two -> artifactory-two.mydomain.com
```

It's rare to see useful feature to become deprecated, I thought that only Apple does that:)